# Crear una campaña para aumentar las inscripciones y visitas

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

He estado analizando a través de este ultimo mes mas o menos, y he podido ver, al menos en mi percepción, que cada vez veo menos gente conectada, o ingresando a la comunidad. No se si sea por que a las horas que ingreso sea de noche en otros países o ya sea muy tarde, o existirá algo con relación a la cantidad de trabajo que tenga cada quien y la fecha que estamos.

En mi caso tengo tiempo que no veo a muchos de los moderadores, y tampoco al administrador, en cuanto a temas de Webcast, hay tiempo que no hay, **quisiera saber si existe alguna problemática, o solo es algo temporal**.

A raíz de esto y muchas cosas mas como, poca gente en el chat, asumo que no todo el mundo lo conoce, he pensado en junto con @ArtEze y @rn3w, en que se debería crear una campaña con la intención de atraer mas personal a la comunidad, con la finalidad de cumplir con todas las metas y crecer mucho mas, y planteo las siguientes soluciones:

1. Aquellos que aun estudien, y conozcan la comunidad, enseñarla a sus compañeros para que estos la conozcan.
2. Si amigos les hacen preguntas, y si tiene o no tiene la respuesta a esta, tratar de que esas personas publiquen sus preguntas aquí.
3. Tratar de popularizara través de grupos y comunidades en redes sociales de programadores la comunidad.
4. Creaciones de eventos que ayuden a que las personas no lleguen, pregunten y se vayan para no volver mas.

Aclaro que con lo anterior no quiero ni crear polémicas, ni que se creen malos entendidos, solo trato de buscar una solución, y de que si alguien, tiene mejores ideas que se puedan agregar, pues bienvenido sea.

Comment: Lo veo buena idea. Yo llevo 43 días en el sitio (bastante más en SOen) y ya la he recomendado a todos los que he podido. Sin embargo, me alegra ver ya algunas preguntas indexadas en google cuando realizas alguna búsqueda específica sobre algún lenguaje. Creo que una comunidad no se crea de la noche a la mañana y con una buena divulgación, pronto será un sitio mucho más grande. Entre todos, haremos un buen sitio de programación en español, estoy seguro :)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con la segunda parte de la publicación, y es algo que siempre intento, sumando mi pequeño grano de arena... No coincido con la primera parte nomás, ya que [el sitio está en continuo crecimiento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3msyD.png) y si hay alguna problemática en particular, no la veo reflejada en los números

Comment: @Mariano pues gracias, y si por eso aclare muchas cosas, quizás no exista ninguna, si no que sea algo de que a mayoría en esta época aumenta el trabajo, supongo yo.

Comment: Sería interesante crear algún cartelito para poder colgar en los tablones de anuncios de las universidades de informática.

Comment: Solo comentar parcialmente lo que comenta Pedro. Debido a la carga de trabajo de cierre del año, ya no he podido participar en el chat y mis aportes en el sitio han caido **:(** Supongo que ha de ser el caso de la mayoria de personas, y no sea porque ya no les interesa participar aqui. Yo en cuanto este mas libre volvere a participar mas :)

Comment: @jasilva claro, por eso dije, que podía ser por lo del trabajo, y aclare que lo que menos quería era malos entendidos.

Comment: Si no viene acompañado de una pedagogía en el uso correcto del sitio ocurrirá que el remedio será peor que la enfermedad.

Comment: @dwarandae pues, dentro del texto y la proposición que realice, creo que puse que cualquier otra idea es bienvenida. :)

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/objetivos-2017-encuentros-locales

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

En los objetivos de 2017 se proponen varias acciones algunas de las cuales coinciden con lo que estas proponiendo incluyendo ciertos apoyos para llevarlos a cabo.

## Respuesta ampliada

Como alguien más mencionó en los comentarios, SOes está en constante crecimiento pero no es ajeno a efectos asociados a las ciclos profesionales y académicos, así que es normal que la actividad decaiga a ratos. Sin embargo, es importante estar atentos y hacer lo posible para que el sitio siga siendo atractivo, particularmente para los expertos quienes son los que están en mejor posición para ofrecer publicaciones de calidad.

Me parece que la mejor forma de atraer expertos es publicando preguntas de calidad, por ello estoy poniendo mi granito de arena al difundir el sitio y pretendo hacer un poquito más haciendo llegar pósters de la comunidad así como la noticia de que SOes existe y que es algo fantástico a otros espacios y grupos empezando por los que tengo más cerca.

## Referencias

- [Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314/objetivos-del-2017-segunda-parte-2)
- [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/objetivos-2017-encuentros-locales)
- https://www.quantcast.com/es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Interesante estilo wikipedístico para responder :) Por lo general, a mí me gusta más poner los enlaces en las partes específicas donde son relevantes, pero supongo que para gustos, colores.

Comment: @fedorqui: Gracias por la edición y el comentario. Me gustaría que se pudieran incluir citas (superíndices) con enlace a la sección de referencias como ocurre en Wikipedia. Mientras tanto, en algunas publicaciones incluyo los enlaces en el cuerpo del mensaje pero en otras como esta, simplemente los agrego al final. En estos casos en lugar de llamar referencia a la sección con los enlaces, debí haberlo puesto, publicaciones relacionadas, weblografía u alguna otro título más apropiado.