# Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)

Tags: discusión

He estado reflexionando sobre el último año del sitio, y me parece excelente todo lo que hemos podido lograr en tan poco tiempo.  Claro, tenemos la plataforma que ha elevado a Stack Overflow en inglés a ser el sitio más accedido por desarrolladores profesionales (y también a los no tan profesionales como yo) a nivel mundial, pero la plataforma no es la receta secreta de nuestro progreso.  Hemos intentado proporcionarles los mejores recursos para obtener la mejor oportunidad de crecimiento para el sitio y, sin duda, hemos hecho grandes logros este año.

Al pensar en los países representados aquí siento más que existen más cosas que nos unen que simplemente el idioma que hablamos a diario. Todos aquí somos gente curiosa, innovadora, trabajadora, y lista para ayudar. El 2017 traerá nuevos retos y pensando en esto, he deseado compartir con ustedes algunos de los planes que tengo para la comunidad para este año.

### ✔️ 1. La graduación del sitio

¡Pocas cosas me causan nervios y alegría a la misma vez como lo de la graduación de nuestro sitio! Hace cuatro años, [la propuesta fue hecha](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) para empezar el sitio en español.  Jachguate fue el que sugirió la propuesta y también fue el primero en ver el sitio en estado Beta privado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder graduar un sitio, es necesario cumplir ciertas especificaciones - mayormente, la del porcentaje de respuestas en el sitio (se necesita el 90%) y también la de la relación entre preguntas y respuestas para cada pregunta.  Ambas líneas necesitan incrementar más antes de podernos graduar.

Estoy seguro que nos graduaremos en el 2017 y pienso que lo podemos hacer a fines de marzo o principios de abril si los números siguen creciendo de la misma manera.  Les advierto que después de que se gradúe el sitio, será necesario el seguir trabajando para superar lo ya obtenido.  Este sitio tiene un potencial enorme y un alcance cuyos limites están por descubrirse.  ¡Estamos a la orilla de lo que se puede alcanzar y esto nos debe motivar y entusiasmar para seguir adelante!

Pónganse listos para celebrar la graduación de nuestro sitio este año.

### ✔️ 2. Preguntas por día

Si algún día les interesa ojear un poco el ranking de los sitios de Stack Exchange, les [comparto este enlace](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).  Al visitar la lista, se darán cuenta que Stack Overflow en español queda más bajo que el undécimo lugar. No sé ustedes, pero si me pongo a pensar en la cantidad de desarrolladores de habla hispana que existen en el mundo, es fácil ver que podemos superar hasta el sitio ruso sin problema.

Para los que no lo saben, el sitio ruso es el más grande de los sitios internacionales y es el que ocupa el tercer lugar entre los sitios de Stack Exchange. Ellos llevan 59K usuarios y nosotros unos 22K.  Ellos llevan unas 180 preguntas por día y nosotros unas 68.  Ellos llevan más de 4 años en existencia y nosotros apenas 1.

Según el 2016, vacilamos entre 60-80 preguntas por día.  Para el 2017, quiero que vacilemos entre 120-140 preguntas al día.  Esto significa un aumento de más de un 75% pero sé que podemos sobrepasar las 200 preguntas al día sin demasiado esfuerzo.  Lo que se necesita para lograr esta meta es:

- correr la voz sobre nuestro sitio
- educar y ayudar a los nuevos usuarios
- continuar con la participación propia

La primera meta que quiero superar es la de sobrepasar las 120 preguntas por día.  Recuerden que este objetivo traerá más que orgullo. Mientras más preguntas tengamos en el sitio, más respuestas existirán para aumentar nuestra base de datos. Esto atraerá a más gente, lo cual nos ayudará a crecer y a poder ayudar a más desarrolladores.  La idea sigue igual -el ayudar a mejorar los recursos de nuestra gente por medio del compartimiento de información precisa.

Actualización enero 2018: [se llegó a 114 preguntas por día](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/05/el-estado-de-stack-overflow-en-espanol-diciembre-2017/).

### 3. Videos introductorios para SOes

Uno de los proyectos que nos ayudaran a educar a los nuevos usuarios es el de los [videos introductorios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/899/video-introductorio-para-soes).  Sigan el enlace para aprender más sobre este proyecto (si es que lo desconocen). Nos falta terminar los videos y compartirlos.  Este es un trabajo que queremos terminar en el 2017.  Si les gustaría ayudar, comuníquense con [FredyFx](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) por medio de la publicación en el Meta.

### 4. Enlaces cruzados (Cross-Linking)

Al hacer una investigación sobre los visitantes de nuestra comunidad, nos dimos cuenta que un gran numero de ellos buscan una respuesta especifica por Google (o similar) lo cual los lleva al sitio en inglés.  Después de encontrar lo que buscan, esos posibles usuarios desaparecen porque no saben que existimos.  Qué lamentable realidad….

Hemos compilado una lista de más de 300 preguntas que son visitadas frecuentemente por gente cuyo browser esta configurado al español y que se botan después de ver esa pregunta.  La idea aquí es de ofrecerles a esos visitantes la oportunidad de ver respuestas en español a esa pregunta y otras.

El proceso funcionaría así:

**...Realidad...**

> Tatiana habla español y trabaja en una empresa de software donde el
> proyecto en el cual esta trabajando resulta en una pregunta  la cual
> no puede solucionar.  Ella no sabe de Stack Overflow en español pero
> siendo muy inteligente y teniendo limitaciones de tiempo, ella decide
> buscar una respuesta por internet.  Tatiana realiza una búsqueda en
> Google lo cual la trae a StackOverflow.com (el sitio en inglés).  No
> entiende todo lo que ve pero sabe que el código que se comparte allí
> le funcionara.  Ella entonces toma el código necesario y se va.

**¡Posibilidad!**

> Tatiana habla español y no sabe de Stack Overflow en español. Se le
> presenta una situación donde se requiere una respuesta a una pregunta
> que no puede solucionar sola.  Realiza una búsqueda en Google y
> encuentra una respuesta que le puede servir.  Al llegar a
> StackOverflow.com se da cuenta de una banner que le indica que la
> misma pregunta se ha hecho en el sitio en español y que existen
> respuestas allí también.  Sorprendida por esta noticia, Tatiana decide
> visitar a es.StackOverflow.com y empieza a interactuar con otros
> miembros lo cual le beneficia no solamente en lo profesional pero
> también en lo personal.  Al participar en la sala de chat se da cuenta
> que hay otros desarrolladores que viven en su ciudad.  Ellos deciden
> juntarse un viernes por la noche para platicar y disfrutar de una cena
> ligera.
>
> Resulta que el grupo se la pasa muy bien y deciden formar un
> “Startup de tech” lo cual crece en pocos meses y todos se vuelven
> completamente ricos al vender su idea a Microsoft.  Tatiana decide
> comprarse una casa en Paris y un perrito bulldog para disfrutar de sus
> ganancias y reflexionar sobre el cambio de vida que le proporciono el
> visitar la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español.

**¿Qué tal, eh?**

Las preguntas que podemos enlazar la pondré en una pregunta diferente en el sitio Meta.  Allí podremos todos buscar y ayudar a conectar las preguntas más vistas en el sitio en inglés con las correspondientes en nuestra comunidad. Si no existe una pregunta correspondiente en español, la podemos crear.  De nuevo, la idea es de compartir.

Bueno, con eso los dejo por ahora y les comparto la segunda parte después. Los comentarios y  las opiniones que tengan por favor compártanlas.  ¿Qué piensan ustedes?

¡Este año puede ser completamente espectacular, de eso estoy seguro!

[***(La segunda parte de los objetivos del 2017)***](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314/objetivos-del-2017-segunda-parte-2)

Comment: Hola Juan. Mencionastes: *Para poder graduar un sitio, es necesario cumplir ciertas especificaciones - mayormente, la del porcentaje de respuestas en el sitio*. En cuanto a esto, justamente hize una pregunta tiempo atrás en cuanto a *cómo* se calcula ese porcentaje ([¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/985/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-estad%C3%ADstica-porcentaje-de-preguntas-contestadas-en-area-51)). Básicamente, quisiera saber hasta qué grado las preguntas de baja calidad tal vez afecten la salida del beta.

Comment: @sstan Te juro que tenía pensado contestarte en algún momento (lo tengo anotado en un listado de cosas pendientes para SOes), pero me distraje con otras cosas. De todas formas, sigo haciendo hincapié en que no es el mejor objetivo a buscar. Entiendo que Juan lo publique entre los objetivos (mejorarlo), pero estoy convencido de que no es, ni debería ser, un limitante.

Comment: @Mariano. Te creo :) y te entiendo. Y tus aportes son siempre muy apreciados. Gracias.

Comment: @Mariano estoy de acuerdo. De hecho [quant.se] se acaba de graduar [hace un mes](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/1512/26065) y tiene un 78%. A todo esto, los enlaces cruzados serían una funcionalidad fantástica, ¡ojalá pueda implementarse!

Comment: @fedorqui y comparemos SOes (74%) con SO (72%) y SOpt (78%)... ¿Acaso no esperaríamos el mismo porcentaje que estos sitios? ;-)

Comment: @Mariano lo que sí veo es que [SOpt se graduó con un 85%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) y [SOru se graduó con un 82%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian). Veo que SOjp sigue en beta con un 80%. Esto me hace pensar que un 80% sí puede ser "exigido" para graduar SOes.

Comment: a ver... ¿el problema es matemático?, para subir un 6% partiendo de una base de 14k preguntas. Se necesitaría contestar el 86% de otras 14k preguntas para alcanzar el 80% general. A menos que la estadística maneje alguna ventana de tiempo que desconozco. ¿hay certezas sobre como se calcula el total?

Comment: @EmanuelVe sí, ya tenemos certezas: ayer lo respondimos en [¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1279/83).

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui XD

Comment: Yo me propongo a utilizar el software de Tatiana.

Comment: @ArtEze si la intención es marcar los puntos ya alcanzados, estando en 123 preguntas por día, diría que el punto **2** ya lo alcanzamos

Comment: @Mariano Es cierto que todavía no superamos al sitio ruso, pero es cierto, se superó el objetivo. Ya le puse el check.

Comment: @ArtEze en el mejor de los casos, podríamos alcanzar a [ru.so] a fines del 2018... Pero yo estoy más que contento viendo que llegamos al nivel de [su] a fin de año/principios del año que viene.