# Autoresponder mi pregunta ya contestada en otro sitio

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

Si hago una pregunta en es.SO y en SO y recibo una respuesta satisfactoria en cualquiera de los dos sitios. ¿Qué debo hacer?

- ¿Esperar a que aparezca una respuesta original de otro usuario?
- ¿Responder a mi pregunta (por supuesto, citando la autoría de la respuesta)?

Comment: Creo que si la respuesta resuelve tu problema deberías responder la otra con la solución del problema y decir donde la encontraste, en este caso la otra pagina de SO

Comment: Autorresponder sería con dos eres, o una erre.

Comment: @ArtEze yo juraría que con una sola r: _autoresponder_. Siempre puedes preguntarlo en [spanish.se] ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui Tendré que esperar. http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19398/autorresponder-va-con-doble-ere-o-una-erre

Comment: @ArtEze por lo que veo, no mucho :P

Answer (score 4):

Muy pronto tendremos la habilidad para juntar a las dos preguntas y sus respuestas.  Pueden leer más sobre esto en [la publicación de los objetivos del 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1) donde platicamos sobre los enlaces cruzados.

Anunciaré el lanzamiento de esta funcionalidad en cuanto este lista para el uso público.