# Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?

Tags: discusión, soporte, encuentros-locales, meetups, promoción-del-sitio

## Pregunta breve

Me gustaría conocer sobre las pautas para usar el nombre y logo del sitio en encuentros locales así como las recomendaciones para hacer sinergia con iniciativas independientes y/o patrocinadas. ¿Ya está publicado esto o menciando el tema en el contexto de los objetivos 2017?

## Explicación breve

Recién encontré [un tuit](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow/status/819590763969478656) de [la cuenta de SOes](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow) con un enlace a [un espacio web](https://www.meetup.com/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/) para coordinar encuentros locales, específicamente en Buenos Aires, Argentina.

¿Hay alguna recomendación o experiencias para hacer cosas similares en otras ciudades? Por ejemplo, yo me encuentro en Monterrey, México.

Supongo que la cosa es empezar con un encuentro de dos :)

Esta semana participé en un encuentro de [Codeando Monterrey](https://www.facebook.com/CodeandoMonterrey/) (brigada Monterrey de [Codeando México](https://www.facebook.com/CodeandoMexico)) el cual me parece que es un grupo muy afin a la comunidad de SOes. Obviamente les platiqué acerca de SOes, espero "leerlos" por aquí frecuentemente :)

Otras eventos similares en los que ya participo o pretendo hacerlo en Monterrey son:

- Las Charlas de los Viernes del [CEDDIE del Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Monterrey](https://www.facebook.com/ceddie.itesm)
- Eventos con el apoyo del [Programa de Colaboradores Principales de Google](https://topcontributor.withgoogle.com/?hl=es)

## Explicación ampliada

La comunicación es un fenómeno muy complejo pero cotidiano por lo que es común subestimar y dar por sentado muchas cosas. Lamentablemente esto dificulta lograr una comunicación efectiva.

Si bien Internet y las distintas formas de comunicación que habilita son maravillosos, estos son restrictivos. En muchas casos las restricciones propias del Internet mas que ser algo "malo", resultan ser algo "bueno" porque promueven mejorar el dominio de las competencias propias de la comunicación, sin embargo, por un lado existen ciertos fenómenos que sólo ocurren en una conversación en persona y por otro existen personas que les cuesta mucho comunicarse y ni se diga, [publicar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

En el caso de SOes me parece que los encuentros locales además de ayudar a fortalcer la cohesión de la comunidad, también pueden ser de mucha utilidad para dar orientación sobre cómo participar y por ende **incrementar el número de publicaciones diarias**.

P.D. Ansioso por recibir [los posters de SOes 2017](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=34858930#34858930)

## Publicaciones relacionadas

- [Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314/objetivos-del-2017-segunda-parte-2)
- [Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/496/mentor%C3%ADa-y-equipos-de-aprendizaje-grupal)
- [Webcasts 2017 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337/webcasts-2017-c%C3%B3mo-y-por-qu%C3%A9-fechas)
- [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185/anuncios-de-promoci%C3%B3n-de-la-comunidad-2017)
- [Crear una campaña para aumentar las inscripciones y visitas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/crear-una-campa%C3%B1a-para-aumentar-las-inscripciones-y-visitas)

---

## Actualización 9 de febrero de 2017

Por el número de votos positivos en un lapso breve de tiempo (12 en 5 días) podría decirse que a la comunidad le interesa que ocurran encuentros locales en el 2017 pero no hay pautas oficiales para este año en particular.

> NOTA: En [Meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) está la etiqueta [meetups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meetups). No he encontrado información específica para lo que aquí estoy preguntando. Como antecedentes generales están
>
> - [Respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1384/65) a otra pregunta en meta
>
>   - [Emmanuel Ve](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/25/emanuel-ve) comparte acerca de un meetup por realizarse próximamente en Argentina.
> - [Stack Overflow Meetups 2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/)
>
>   - Publicación en el blog oficial
> - [Community-wide meetup event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285063/289691)
>
>   - Publicación en meta con votos negativos aparentemente por carecer de investigación, pero con respuesta y comentarios útiles.

### Propuesta (cambios "mayores" el 15 de marzo de 2017)

1. Si estas interesado en organizar un encuentro local (meetup),

   1.1. Coordinate con al menos otro miembro de la comunidad para organizar un encuentro
   1.2. Publica una página web con la información del evento
2. Una vez que haya una página web con los datos del evento, agrega [una pregunta en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) que incluyas

   2.1 Las etiquetas [meetup](/questions/tagged/meetup) y [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n).
   2.2 El nombre y enlace a la página web del evento.
   2.3 Un resumen breve de quienes y cómo organizaron el evento de tal forma que sirva de inspiración y guía para quienes les gustaría organizar uno.

Comment: Meetups! esto es una excelente propuesta para los miembros que conforman esta comunidad y alentar a nuevos miembros a unirse. En estos momentos me encuentro en CDMX pero también puedo estar en Monterrey, saludos.

Comment: @95 ¡Que bien! Pues los eventos de los viernes son todos los viernes  a las 4:30 pm, hasta mayo. Luego se retoman de agosto a noviembre, al menos en teoría. Si andas por acá (es decir, en Monterrey) un viernes avísame para darte detalles. Firma usuario 65 :).

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @Jorgesys, ¡montemos meetups! Yo me apunto a los que se hagan en España :)

Comment: En Madrid podría dar una charla sobre la comunidad :)

Comment: @Jorgesys: He puesto [algunos detalles](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35268471#35268471) sobre las reuniones de la brigada Monterrey de Codeando México en la [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52988/hackers-civicos) "Hackers Cívicos"

Comment: Si alguien está interesado de crear un evento para anunciar con y sobre SOes en España, sea Madrid, Barcelona o Málaga que me avise. Madrid y Barcelona tengo buenos contacto para organizar algo guapo. :)

Comment: @Jorgesys: Recién cree un sitio en meetup.com para manejar los meetups en Monterrey ¿te unes? - > https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/

Comment: @aldanux Si alguien quiere en Bilbao, me apunto a montarlo si es necesario.

Answer (score 2):

## Recomendaciones

1. Hazlo simple

   - Empieza por organizar encuentros donde el tema central sea fomentar la convivencia **fuera de línea** y que incluya a miembros de Stack Overflow en español. Considera incluir la promoción de la participación en el sitio.
2. Comunícalo

   - Habla con anticipación con [Juan M](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m), como mínimo un mes antes, acerca del propósito y fecha del encuentro local. Juan te podría dar recomendaciones considerando las circunstancias particulares del evento que propones, además, te podría apoyar gestionando patrocinio de SO para alimentos, bebidas, stickers, camisetas... ¡No hay límites!, bueno, hasta donde el presupuesto alcance XD. Referencia: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/Una-receta-para-promover-nuestra-comunidad/
3. Compártelo

   - Antes del evento convoca, durante el evento toma fotos y/o video, después del evento, publica lo mejor del mismo.

## Información adicional

Ejemplos recientes de grupos que organizan encuentros locales

- Buenos Aires

  - https://www.meetup.com/es/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/
- Monterrey

  - https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/

Ejemplos antiguos (mas de un año)

- Londres

  - https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-Meetups/