# ¿Qué esfuerzos han sido igualados con fondos?

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

Dijo Juan M en su [blog de julio de 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/Una-receta-para-promover-nuestra-comunidad/):

> (..)
>
> ### Se igualará el esfuerzo con fondos
>
> Cualquier comunidad que demuestre suficiente empeño e ideas innovativas para promover su sitio se le ofrecerá un presupuesto y recursos para ayudar a realizar esas ideas. Piénsalo como un sistema donde igualamos fondos, excepto que igualaremos fondos con innovación, recursos, esfuerzo, e ideas de la comunidad. Pero, tiene que nacer de su comunidad, ustedes son los expertos, no nosotros.
>
> El igualar los fondos con su esfuerzo asegurará que: 1. Los recipientes están invertidos en el mejoramiento del sitio 2. Las comunidades saben que sus esfuerzos regresaran para ayudar a mejorar el sitio.
>   (..)

Me gustaría conocer qué ideas surgidas de la comunidad han recibido un presupuesto. No se las publicita lo suficiente, no he visto ninguna. Quizá alguna me interese y pueda contribuir.

Answer (score 7):

## Este es un caso...

En Buenos Aires, Argentina estamos organizando [un meetup](https://www.meetup.com/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires) para promocionar la comunidad.

StackOverflow, por medio de JuanM ofreció un dinero para dar comida y bebida a los asistentes, el cual es mas que suficiente.

Meetup de StackOverflow en Español - Buenos Aires #1: La fecha Tentativa es el día 29 de Marzo próximo, zona Microcentro (la dirección exacta se comunicará por la plataforma Meetup cuando este confirmada la fecha). El cupo es de aprox. 50 personas. El contenido del meetup es, por ahora secreto :P ... no queremos arruinar la sorpresa.

Comment: Gracias por compartirlo :)

Comment: Me parece genial. Me gustaría saber qué debo hacer o cómo debemos proceder para organizar uno similar en Bogotá, Colombia.

Comment: @dwarandae: Te podría interesar esta otra pregunta -> http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/objetivos-2017-encuentros-locales?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @dwarandae simplemente me comunique con juanM y le explique la idea.

Comment: @dwarandae Seria genial uno en Bogota! Asi mismo mirar si se puede promocionar en las universidades.