# Encuentro local en Monterrey, México, 17 de marzo de 2017

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales, meetups

Actualización importante

El [primer encuentro local de SOes](https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/events/237888588/) es este viernes 17 de marzo, en Innovaction Gym, Monterrey, México a las 19:00 hrs tiempo del Centro de México (UTC -6), con la presencia de [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m).

---

Conversando con [flxtr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr) en el chat acordamos realizar un encuentro local (meetup) en Monterrey entre el 17 de marzo de 2017 y para ayudarnos a organizar esto he creado un [grupo](https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/) en http://www.meetup.com/es/.

Por lo pronto, como decimos en México el evento es de traje...

- Traje comida
- Traje bebida
- ...

La fecha, hora, lugar, menú, programa, etc. están por determinarse. Los interesados, favor suscribirse al [grupo](https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/) en meetup.com.

Por supuesto, se aceptan patrocinios :)

Relacionado

- [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/)

---

## Actualización

### Reseña sobre el evento

https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/messages/boards/thread/50711146

### 13 de marzo de 2017

Se ha realizado la que prácticamente es la actualización final [del evento](https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/events/237888588/) en meetup.com

### 28 de febrero de 2017

- Ya está confirmado el lugar, será en el Innovaction Gym del Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Monterrey.
- Contaremos con la partición de Juan M.
- Se actualizó el evento en Meetup.com para indicar el lugar y se agregó una descripción. Faltaría detallar el programa.

### 21 de febrero de 2017.2

El evento en el grupo en meetup.com se publicará "en breve", mientras tanto, los datos tentativos:

Fecha tentativa: viernes 17 de marzo de 2017
Hora tentativa: 7 a 9 pm
Lugar: Por determinar

### 21 de febrero de 2017.1

Hace unas 6 horas tuve una videollamada con JuanM, quien me confirmó que al igual del Meetup de Buenos Aires Argentina, contamos con el apoyo de SOes para la comida y bebida, sólo hay que avisar la fecha definitiva, ... y cruzar los dedos que la "tramitología" (*paper work*) fluya y que todo coincida en tiempo y forma, como es usual en estas cosas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54005/discussion-between-ruben-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: Usuarios de México, en caso de que quieras dejar algún comentario / invitación a un chat: http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/153857/top-n-users-in-country?top=100&FullCountryName=xico&ShortCountryName=MX

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: y en otras partes de mexico? no se harian? :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He hablado con Rubén sobre este evento y me parece genial que se organice algo así en Monterrey. Sin duda han habido problemitas sobre el respaldo de SOes para este evento.

@Luiggi tiene toda la razón en preguntar si hay respaldo "oficial" o no y le falto a Rubén decir que había hablado conmigo sobre esto - tal vez por la emoción de formar este meetup. He tenido otras oportunidades de hablar con Rubén y de verlo en acción en una o dos conferencias y le tengo confianza. Lamentablemente, la comunidad no sabe de eso y falto el anunciar que se había hablado conmigo ya.

Apoyamos el interés de la gente en México para reunirse y colaborar un rato al disfrutar de una convivencia de cara a cara. Para otros meetups, es necesario el hablar conmigo para poder confirmar el partrocinio de SOes.

¡Gracias a ustedes por su apoyo!

Comment: Gracias por tus amables palabras Juan.