# ¿Dónde puedo ver comunidades que se reúnen alrededor de México de SO Español?

Tags: discusión, chat

¡Hola a todos! Soy Ricardo de Codeando Monterrey, nos interesa mucho ayudar a la comunidad de SO español. ¿Dónde podemos ver a las personas que ya están empujando la iniciativa?

Comment: Bienvenido Ricardo. En el sitio principal es para preguntas sobre programación. Las preguntas acerca de la comunidad, cómo funciona el sitio y otras que no sean propiamente de programación deben realizarse en [meta]. Te sugiero que hagas el [tour].

Comment: Este es una comunidad multinacional creo que hay personas que no saben incluso donde queda "Monterrey" (de hecho existe un Monterey en California US) ni mucho menos conocen la comunidad que comentas, sería buena opción dar más detalles.

Comment: hey espera, no conoces al usuario Ruben?, me parece te menciono en uno de sus posts. Agrega un enlace de la comunidad! :)

Comment: @Jorgesys: Te he de confesar que Ricardo y yo si nos conocemos. Él es algo así como mi mentor en lo que al hacking cívico se refiere. En la Hack Night del jueves, estando juntos y entre hacking y bromas publicamos la pregunta-respuesta y voté para "cerrarla"... entre las cosas que le mencioné la política de votos indica que no se permiten los votos por personas del mismo equipo cuando se hace con el fin de ganar reputación. La pregunta-respuesta han sido "honestas", no me había dicho que era lo que iba a preguntar, ni yo le había dicho que era lo que le iba a responder. Sólo le dije pregunta.

Comment: no creo que esto sea para ganar votos ni que sea mala pregunta aquí, al contrario!, pero creo que sería bueno que agregara más información,  de hecho busque información y encontré que tienen muchos seguidores en sus eventos :0 !

Comment: No lo menciono tanto por tí, sino por otros que podrían pasar por aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más apropiado es que te pongas en contacto con [Juan M](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m), quien es el Gerente de la Comunidad.

Mientras tanto, te comparto que al día de hoy no contamos con un directorio de comunidades locales que realicen eventos en México acerca de Stack Overflow en español.

Tomando como excusa la visita de [Flxtr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr) a Monterrey en marzo, estamos proponiendo un encuentro local "express". Los detalles en

[Encuentro local en Monterrey, México, 17 de marzo de 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436/encuentro-local-en-monterrey-m%C3%A9xico-17-de-marzo-de-2017)