# Falta traducir descripción de medalla "Not a robot"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

## Panorama

Recientemente se agregó la medalla [Not a robot](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/not-a-robot) a la [lista de medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), lo cual me da muchísima alegría, porque es un paso más a la consolidación del sitio.

## Reporte / Propuesta

### Página de la medalla / lista de medallas / y cualquier otro lugar

**Nombre de la medalla**

> Not a robot

Así como Stack Overflow que no se traduce, sugiero no traducir porque lo considero un signo de la identidad y sentido de pertenencia a la comunidad global de programadores en la red de sitios Stack Exchange.

**Descripción de la medalla**

> Met a Stack Overflow employee at an [event where Stack Overflow was an organizer or participant](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) with 50 or more attendees

***Traducción propuesta***

> Reúnete con un empleado de Stack Overflow en un evento donde Stack Overflow fue un organizador o participante. Aplican restricciones.

Lo de "Aplican restricciones", aunque es obvio para algunos, vale la pena mencionar que al empleado de Stack Overflow se le debe dar el número de usuario  u otro método de identificación apropiado, ya que Stack Overflow permite los homónimos, y obviamente, si no le das tus datos, no podrán asignarte la medalla.

Del enlace en la descripción de la medalla, https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

**Pestaña del navegador**

> Get a silver Not a Robot badge - Stack Overflow en español.

***Traducción propuesta***

> Obtén la medalla de plata Not a Robot - Stack Overflow en español.

**Título**

> ### Upcoming Stack Overflow Events

***Traducción propuesta***

> Próximos eventos de Stack Overflow

**Cuerpo**

> #### Where to find us if you’re looking for a Not a Robot badge
>
> Our [“Not A Robot” badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335432) can be earned by attending an event with at least 50 participants where Stack Overflow is the organizer or
>   where one or more of our employees are actively participating in an
>   event.
>
> Come out and meet us and get verified as a real human at the following events. We update this frequently, so stay tuned for more
>   events closer to you.
>
> #### Upcoming Events
>
> There are no events being planned right now.

***Traducción propuesta***

Por hacer.

## Hilos relacionados

### Stack Overflow Meta en español

- [Encuentro local en Monterrey, México, 17 de marzo de 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436/encuentro-local-en-monterrey-m%C3%A9xico-17-de-marzo-de-2017)
- [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/objetivos-2017-encuentros-locales)
- [¿Dónde puedo ver comunidades que se reúnen alrededor de México de SO Español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1458/d%C3%B3nde-puedo-ver-comunidades-que-se-re%C3%BAnen-alrededor-de-m%C3%A9xico-de-so-espa%C3%B1ol/)

### Stack Overflow Meta (en inglés)

- [A New Silver Badge That Robots Simply Can't Win](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win)

Comment: Felicitaciones por la medalla! Un detalle: no entiendo por qué considerás que dejarlo en inglés es un signo de la identidad. Normalmente estoy a favor de nombrar en inglés todo lo que llamamos en inglés en el ámbito profesional. Pero en este caso, se debe al [reCAPTCHA de Google](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha) ([fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335432/5290909)), que normalmente vemos en el sitio como `"No soy un robot"`.

Comment: Completamente en desacuerdo con no traducir "Not a Robot". No estoy seguro si darte un +1 porque el tema es interesante. O un -1 por estar en desacuerdo con esa cuestión.

Comment: En lugar de _"Reúnite"_ debería ser __Reunirse__, porque se está expresando el requisito para obtener una medalla.... ups... hice una sugerencia ñ_ñ

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Me parece que en este tipo de casos, en los que se encuentra útil el tema de la pregunta, pero no se está del todo de acuerdo, el responder con una alternativa, tal como lo has hecho, es una excelente forma de proceder ya que entre las formas de dar relevancia a un hilo es la de agregar respuestas.

Comment: @toledano: Gracias por el comentario. Me parece que se refiere al estilo. Me pregunto si existe un [manual de estilo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_de_estilo) para la documentación oficial.

Comment: @Mariano : Gracias por las felicitaciones. Creo que mi subconciente se quedó con eso debido a [A New Silver Badge That Robots Simply Can't Win](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win). Creo que tengo que re-leerlo y repensar la propuesta de nombre de la medalla.

Comment: Qué bueno que se use la medalla aquí también, está será difícil de conseguir. Por cierto, siendo estrictos, ¿no debería haber al menos 50 asistentes? En la [página del evento](https://www.meetup.com/es/Stack-Overflow-en-Espanol-Monterrey/events/237888588/) en Meetup se mencionan 37.

Comment: @fedorqui Tienes toda la razón. Siendo que este fue el primer evento, y queriendo aprovechar la novedad para poder ofrecer la misma medalla aquí sin tener que esperar a otro evento, decidí tomar una decisión ejecutiva y otorgar esas medallas esta vez solamente. Si me hubiera esperado, tal vez mis compañeros de trabajo no hubieran estado dispuestos a ayudarnos a tener este medalla aquí.

Comment: @JuanM ¡y me parece fantástico que otorgarais la medalla igualmente! Incluso si hubiera sido un encuentro de apenas 5 personas, creo que reunirse con alguien de [se] es lo suficientemente relevante como para que se dé tal medalla. Gracias por la iniciativa y por empujar para que esté también en este sitio. Solo me queda preguntar: ¿para cuándo una conferencia en España? :P

Comment: @fedorqui en mayo....

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1693/una-nueva-medalla-de-plata-que-los-robots-no-pueden-ganar? ¡Listo!

Comment: @JuanM: Casi. En http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/not-a-robot y en http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges la descripción está 50-50: "Met a Stack Overflow employee at an event where Stack Overflow was an organizer or participant with 50 or more attendees. Esta medalla se puede otorgar varias veces.". Tal vez sea cosa de esperar a que se propaguen los cambios ¿mañana? :D

Comment: @Rubén dame chansa de actualizar lo demás - jajaja

Comment: @JuanM Está bien, te doy chansa XD

Comment: @Rubén Ok, esta ya lista la traducción de la medalla también. Dale un poco de tiempo para que se actualize la base de datos. Cualquier cosa que falte, ya sabes... :D

Comment: @JuanM celebro totalmente el esfuerzo para seguir implementando características en el sitio. Esto es donde debería estar el foco, y algo más de lo que podemos estar orgullosos de que tenemos, sumado al blog, webcasts y todas las que vendrán (que no están en muchos otros sitios e incluso nos envidian por eso!).

Comment: @JuanM cuando puedas, ¿podrás dar más información sobre el evento en España? Lo comenté en el chat y la gente no lo conoce, pero seguro que avisando con tiempo muchos haremos lo posible por asistir.

Comment: @fedorqui Estoy planeando el evento ahora, no tengo fechas todavía pero en cuanto las tenga las comparto. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Una nueva medalla de plata que los robots no pueden ganar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1693/una-nueva-medalla-de-plata-que-los-robots-no-pueden-ganar)?

¡Listo! He aquí la traducción. Dejen sus preguntas y comentarios allí.

Answer (score 4):

Este es un sitio en español. Es más importante facilitar su uso a quien no sabe inglés que perseguir una cierta identidad. Identidad que de todas formas es alcanzable con idiomas distintos.

Como traducción propongo:

**Nombre de la medalla**

> Not a robot

***Traducción propuesta***

> No soy un robot

**Descripción de la medalla**

> Met a Stack Overflow employee at an [event where Stack Overflow was an organizer or participant](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) with 50 or more attendees

***Traducción propuesta***

> Reúnete con un empleado de Stack Overflow en un [evento donde Stack Overflow fue un organizador o participante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) con 50 o más asistentes.
>
> Al empleado de Stack Overflow se le debe dar el número de usuario  u otro método de identificación apropiado, ya que Stack Overflow permite los homónimos, y obviamente, si no le das tus datos, no podrán asignarte la medalla.

**Pestaña del navegador**

> Get a silver Not a Robot badge - Stack Overflow en español.

***Traducción propuesta***

> Obtén la medalla de plata No soy un Robot - Stack Overflow en español.

**Título**

> ### Upcoming Stack Overflow Events

***Traducción propuesta***

> ### Próximos eventos de Stack Overflow

**Cuerpo**

> #### Where to find us if you’re looking for a Not a Robot badge
>
> Our [“Not A Robot” badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335432) can be earned by attending an event with at least 50 participants where Stack Overflow is the organizer or
> where one or more of our employees are actively participating in an
> event.
>
> Come out and meet us and get verified as a real human at the following events. We update this frequently, so stay tuned for more
> events closer to you.
>
> #### Upcoming Events
>
> There are no events being planned right now.

***Traducción propuesta***

> #### Donde encontrarnos si quieres conseguir la medalla No soy un Robot.
>
> Nuestra [Medalla“No soy un Robot” badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335432) se puede conseguir atendiendo a un evento en que haya al menos 50 asistentes que haya sido organizado por Stack Overflow o en que uno o más empleados de Stack Overflow participen activamente.
>
> Ven y conócenos y se verificado como un humano de carne y hueso en los siguientes eventos. Actualizamos esto con frecuencia, permanece atento a posibles eventos que sucedan cerca de ti.
>
> #### Próximos Eventos.
>
> No hay eventos planeados ahora mismo.