# Una nueva medalla de plata que los robots no pueden ganar

Tags: discusión, medallas

No socializamos mucho en Stack Overflow en español o en nuestro sitio Meta. Pero eso no quiere decir que ser sociales o tener conversaciones informales sea malo - solo que preferimos que la gente se socialice en otros lugares.

Otros lugares para nosotros resulta ser el estar en persona. Cuando es el momento de recibir comentarios honestos, abiertos y lúcidos sobre todo lo que estamos construyendo, hemos decidido que necesitamos buscarlo en entornos informales y personales. Recibimos una *enorme* cantidad de valor en nuestras discusiones meta pero hay algo especial acerca de las conversaciones más relajadas hechas en persona, donde es más eficaz la comunicación en vez de usar los pings en el chat o los comentarios.

Esta medalla es especial en cómo se gana y se otorga. Me gustaría aludir brevemente sobre el fondo y algunos detalles técnicos empezando con:

#### ¿Cómo sabremos cuándo se debe otorgar la medalla?

Por ahora, un empleado te preguntará por tu dirección de correo electrónico (la misma que usas cuando inicias sesión con SOes). Tendremos a una o más personas en el evento que podrán recoger tu información. Por esta razón no *cada* evento será apto para poder recibir la medalla. Si un empleado es el que esta dando la charla o la presentación en el evento, haremos el mayor esfuerzo para ayudarles a poder conseguir tu información. Ten en cuenta que esto no va a ser posible siempre pero no prevemos que esto suceda regularmente.

Estamos buscando una manera más automática de otorgar esta medalla. Por ejemplo, usar un código QR al entregar pegatinas. **Estamos abiertos a sus ideas**. Seguiremos otorgando la medalla manualmente por ahora mientras continuamos buscando otros eventos para patrocinar o para participar con el afán de poder conocerlos personalmente.

#### ¿Se puede ganar esta medalla más de una vez?

Sí. El propósito de esta medalla es ofrecer un incentivo adicional para que dejen sus actividades usuales de algún jueves normal para salir a platicar con nosotros si es que estamos en un lugar cercano.

Si ganar otra medalla resulta un incentivo suficiente para despegarte de otro juego de Magic the Gathering, estaremos súper contentos.

#### ¿Es suficiente con aparecer para recibir la medalla?

Casi. Incluso cuando cambiemos a un sistema automatizado para otorgar la medalla todavía necesitarán recibir algo de parte nuestra para poder reclamar la medalla. No hay ningún problema si no quieren venir a interactuar o a platicar mucho con nosotros. No pediremos que nadie lo haga. Pero estaremos allí por si quieren pasar tiempo con nosotros y estaremos creando una oportunidad deliberada para hablar con nosotros por si desean compartir algo.

#### ¡Nunca recibiré esta medalla! ¡Estoy en [país]!

Espera, espera… acabamos de mencionar que continuamos buscando otros eventos para patrocinar o para participar con el afán de poder conocerlos personalmente. Este esfuerzo es global. Una de las razones por la que debe de haber al mínimo 50 personas participando en el evento (no solamente una reunión informal) es para mitigar que algunas personas tengan una ventaja sobre otras simplemente por su proximidad.

Con eventos planeados para los EE.UU.,  America del Sur y diferentes partes de Europa y de Asia, pensamos que tenemos un comienzo aceptable. Algunas medallas son difíciles de ganar y muchos no las obtendrán - un ejemplo es la medalla de Beta la cual ya no se puede ganar. Haremos lo posible por asegurarnos que existan suficientes oportunidades en suficientes lugares.

#### ¿Cómo sabremos a qué eventos podremos asistir?

Por ahora, habrá una publicación aquí donde los tendremos informados. Idealmente esto es algo que pueden encontrar en Stack Overflow (por medio de un *feed* que puedan descargar) pero queremos asegurarnos que tengamos todo lo necesario para la automatización antes de ir a construir algo así.

#### ¿Por qué se llama “No soy un robot"?

Si lo estás preguntando, quiere decir que te has topado con nuestros [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) lo cual te hace extraordinariamente afortunado o sugiere que no usas mucho el internet. :)

Todos sabemos que la *mayoría* de ustedes no son hechos de hojalata y remaches pero pensamos que el nombre es un poco juguetón y se verá bien en el panel de las medallas.

#### ¿Cuándo se lanzará esto?

Verán a gente con esta medalla en el sitio ya.

Una lista de los eventos donde se otorgará la medalla se encuentra aquí:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

#### ¿Es esto específico para Stack Overflow solamente?

No. Los sitios internacionales de Stack Overflow también participarán en esta promoción.

¿Preguntas o comentarios? Favor de dejar una respuesta.

> Publicación original en inglés: [A New Silver Badge That Robots Simply Can't Win](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win)

Comment: ¿se requiere que 50 usuarios de SOes se anoten en la lista? o ¿que 50 personas asistan al evento, de los cuales solo un grupo son miembros de SOes?

Comment: @EmanuelVe se requiere que haya más de 50 personas en el evento, sean parte de SOes on no. El único requisito aparte de este es que un empleado de la empresa este presente como keynote, speaker, encargado de un kiosco, o un presentador.

Comment: @Flxtr Los idiomas se escriben en mayúscula en inglés, en español, al igual que los días de la semana, se escriben en minúscula. Referencia: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=may%C3%BAsculas

Comment: @Rubén no logro comprender tu comentario, ¿te refieres a que puse Stack Overflow en ***Español*** al inicio?

Comment: @Flxtr Sí, a eso me refiero.

Comment: @Rubén ¡oh ya veo! ya quedó corregido :)

Comment: Oye Juan, tú también deberías tener esa medalla, ¿no? Mira a ver si hablas con algún empleado de [se] para que te la den, que no sale en [tu perfil](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m?tab=badges) ;P

Comment: @federqui Desafortunadamente, yo sí soy un robot.

Comment: @JuanM [bip bu bu bop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf_TlCM6Ofg)

Comment: @jasilva jajaja

Comment: @fedorqui Me sabe mal marcar una pregunta antigua como duplicado de una nueva. No me parece la mejor solución pero me parece aceptable. Si la marcas así te apoyaré. Edit: tarde, ya está hecho.

Answer (score 5):

Un detalle, sólo un detalle mínimo:
Sabiendo que el nombre viene del [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) de Google que se usa en el sitio, ¿no quedaría mejor agregarle `"un"` al nombre de la medalla para que quede igual?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Propuesta de nombre: `No soy un robot`

---

PD: Le había [comentado](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=35621288#35621288) sobre la medalla a [Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%C3%A9n), y no me imaginé que lo fuesen a implementar en SOes. ¡Fue una muy grata sorpresa ver que el foco está en las cosas que le suman valor al sitio! Siendo constructivos se logran objetivos que nos diferencian de otros sitios.

Comment: Y perdón si es una molestia tener que editar, pero me suena un poco raro "No soy robot".

Comment: Cambie el titulo de la medalla a "No soy un robot." Suena mejor. :)

Comment: [Los robots protestan contra la discriminación en Internet.](http://bazinganews.com.br/index.php/2017/02/17/robots-protestam-contra-discriminacao-na-internet/)

Answer (score 4):

¡Gran iniciativa! Yo no quiero ser un robot... ¡quiero esta medalla! :)

La página de eventos está en inglés, tal y como comentó Rubén. Además, el texto dice:

> Our [“Not A Robot”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win) badge can be earned by attending an event with at least 50 participants where Stack Overflow is the organizer or where one or more of our employees are actively participating in an event.

con un enlace a la publicación original en inglés de Stack Overflow. Sería interesante cambiar dicho enlace para que apuntara a esta publicación en español.

Answer (score 2):

Juan M:

En la sección ¿Cuando se lanzará esto vivo? se incluye el enlace

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

He observado que también existe el siguiente URL

https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

Las páginas de ambos URLs están en inglés pero en el caso del segungo la pestaña [Past](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past) dice

> There are no events being planned right now.

siendo que en [la del primero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past) se listan varios eventos.

Para todos los eventos de Stack Overflow. ¿Se piensa tener

- una página de eventos con todos los eventos independientemente del idioma?
- una página de eventos para los eventos en español y otra para los eventos en inglés?

Comment: nuestro enlace falta traducilro: http://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

Comment: y no figura el evento de Monterrey http://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past

Comment: El evento de Monterrey no lo podré poner porque hubieron menos de 50 participantes que se reservaron y menos que asistieron.