# Las etiquesta [meetups] y [encuentros-locales] no tienen wiki / guia de uso ¿Recomendaciones?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, encuentros-locales, meetups

Hace tiempo que no estoy activo en Stack Overflow en español. Recien vuelvo a mirar Meta, empezando por las etiquetas [meetups](/questions/tagged/meetups) y [encuentros-locales](/questions/tagged/encuentros-locales), veo que no tienen wiki.

Estoy enterado de algunas cosas que han cambiado a nivel de la red pero no de los detalles locales

¿Algo en particular que deba saber acerca de como se está manejando los wikis de etiqueta en Meta recientemente?

¿En otras palabras, por donde empiezo para ponerme al día?

En particular, me gustaría retomar lo de los encuentros locales. Yo me encuentro en Monterrey. No lo tomen como una promesa todavía. Estoy explorando, midiendo fuerzas. Hace unos momentos publiqué una respuesta en Meta Stack Exchange. Dependiendo de sus respuestas y comentarios podría hacer una traducción si fuera relevante y necesaria. Por lo pronto dejo los enlaces

Pregunta : [Is it time for a SE Volunteer Labor Union or similar organization?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338316/289691)

Esta pregunta fue publicada en 2019. En la respuesta menciono porque estoy respondiendo. En breve, se debe a lo que está pasando este año en general, en Stack Exchange y en mi persona.

[Respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394859/289691)

---

## Progreso

Publiqué una pregunta en Stack Overflow Meta en relación a la medalla "no soy un robot" que se otorga en los encuentros locales y casos especiales cuando uno se encuentra con un empleado de Stack Exchange, Inc. -> [The Stack Overflow events page only include events until 2020. Besides COVID-19, what else I am missing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427259/1595451)

Como esta semana es día de Acción de Gracias, un festivo importante en los Estados Unidos, no es de extrañar que no tenga respuesta todavía.

---

## Relacionado

- [Objetivos 2017 ¿Encuentros locales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1371/65)

Comment: No hay ninguna novedad, que no sepas :p... agregales la wiki que creas correspondiente, sin problemas!

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Qué tal si se hace[meetups] sinonimo de ( ---> ) [encuentros-locales]? Las dos etiquetas fueron creadas en 2017 en el link incluido en la pregunta. [meetups] sólo tiene 4 preguntas, [encuentros-locales], 14, además de que está en español. ¿Cómo se procede? ¿Fast track (ya con este comentario es suficiente), edito esta pregunta para "actualizarla" o creo una nueva?

Comment: @gbianchi He creado una sala -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149830/  . Al parecer el último post sobre encuentro fue en Valencia, en 2019. Primero que quiero estoy buscando ponerme al dia con [es.so], quizas mire un poco [tag:javascript] y [tag:google-apps-script] y una que otra etiqueta relacionada. A la par, también voy a iniciar, a ponerme al día en temas de orientación a usuarios de servicios digitales gratuitos, educación, seguridad, privacidad, autonomía, coordinación. No tengo todavía un plan concreto. Por lo pronto sólo estoy explorando.

Comment: @gbianchi Por favor dale las sugerencias del wiki de [meta-tag:encuentros-locales]

Answer (score 0):

Mi interpretación de los votos es que el consenso es que le parece bien que se agreguen los wiki the etiqueta.

Aprovecho para darle mas visibilidad a dicho en un comentario. Considero que [encuentros-locales] es nuetra "versión" de [meetups], por lo que la segunda debería hacerse sinónimo de la primera, es decir:

[meetups] ---> [encuentros-locales]

Creo que la única forma de aplicar esto será que intervenga un moderador, por lo que sus votos y comentarios son importantes.

Mientras tanto me enfocaría en [encuentros-locales].

Comment: Se te mezcló el inglés con el español al parecer, probablemente quisiste decir _wiki de etiqueta_ :)